# difference between isoFileWriter.Write() and isoFileWriter.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, .net, windows

When we use isolated storage in c# we have two functions from isoFileWriter. can someone explain the difference between `isoFileWriter.Write()` and `isoFileWriter.WriteLine()`

I am using below code:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myspace = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
myspace.CreateDirectory("Emotions");
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Emotions\\history.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myspace))
{
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
    {
        isoFileWriter.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `Write` and `WriteLine`?

Comment: It is actually a basic question obvious from the names of the methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [StreamWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx) and [StreamWriter.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx).

The main difference between the two methods is that `WriteLine` will write a new line to the file, where `Write` will just write the data (without a new line character).

Calling `isoFileWriter.WriteLine()` will just write a new line to the file.  If you were to call `WriteLine` while passing a parameter, ie: `isoFileWriter.WriteLine("Foo")`, it would write `Foo` followed by a new line.  `isoFileWriter.Write("Foo")`, on the other hand, would just write `Foo` without the new line character.

Answer (score 1):

```
Write() vs WriteLine()
```

That typical of text stream. The difference is `WriteLine` writes a new line after the text

```
iso.Write('a'); 
iso.Write('b');
```

will output `ab`

```
iso.WriteLine('a'); //puts a new line after a
iso.Write('b'); //the next output will be on the same line as b
```

will output

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `System.IO.StreamWriter` is used to write characters to a stream in a specific encoding. I believe that it is better to use the class `StreamWriter` to append or write text to a specific file and control the writer (class) later.

### Structure

---

Consider having a `StreamWriter` called `_TextWriter` created using the following example

```
StreamWriter _TextWriter = new StreamWriter(Path)
```

and another `StreamWriter` called `_TextWriter2` created using the following example

```
StreamWriter _TextWriter2 = new StreamWriter(Path, true);
```

If you may notice, our `StreamWriter` called `_TextWriter2` has got two arguments: `Path` and a boolean `true`

Using `true` here simply tells the class that it will be used to **APPEND** characters to a file that the class may create or already exists. Otherwise, if you leave this blank or insert `false` the file will be overwritten.

**Here's an example**

Consider having a file name `Path` which contains TWO lines with the following content

> This is the first line
>   
>  This is the second line

By using the following code, you'll only have ONE line in your document (`Path`) which will be **Hello**

```
_TextWriter.WriteLine("Hello");
```

By using the following code, you'll have THREE lines in your document (`Path`) representing the following content:

> This is the first line
>   
>  This is the second line
>   
>  Hello

```
_TextWriter2.WriteLine("Hello");
```

---

Now let's move to your question, what is the difference between `Write()` and `WriteLine()`

### Write() and WriteLine()

---

The answer is simple, using the method `Write()` will write characters to the last available line to a specific stream if you have `true` set up as a boolean for `append` but will overwrite the content of a specific file if you leave the boolean `append` blank or set it to `false`.

**Here's an example**

**Consider the following**

- You have a file name `D:\MyDocument.txt`
- The file contains the following content

> This is my first line
>   
>  This is my second line

You have the following code :

```
StreamWriter _TextWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\MyDocument.txt");
_TextWriter.Write("Hello");  
_TextWriter.Close(); //Save and Close the StreamWriter
```

What do you expect to happen?
The contents of the file `D:\MyDocument.txt` will change to the following

> Hello

This is because you did not specify whether you want to append or not in the above code and because the default value for append is `false`, the `StreamWriter` will not append to the file and thus the file will be overwritten by the new content.

**Another Example**

**Consider the following**

- You have a file name `D:\MyDocument.txt`
- The file contains the following content

> This is my first line
>   
>  This is my second line

You have the following code :

```
StreamWriter _TextWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\MyDocument.txt", true);
_TextWriter.Write("Hello");  
_TextWriter.Close(); //Save and Close the StreamWriter
```

What do you expect to happen?

The contents of the file `D:\MyDocument.txt` will change to the following

> This is my first line
>   
>  This is my second lineHello

The file was not overwritten by the word `Hello` because you have set the boolean `append` to `true` but did you notice this? The second line of the file has changed to

> This is my first line
>   
>  **This is my second lineHello**

This means that `Hello` was appended to the last line available, this is because you have used `Write()` which will append the text to the last line available.

### Summary

---

So, if you would not like this to happen, you may use `WriteLine()` which will create a line at the end of the file first. Then, **append or overwrite** the file with the characters you specify.